# How to simulate SMS receiving at Genymotion

Tags: broadcastreceiver, genymotion

I have to test my app on genymotion, my app listen to BroadcastReceiver but my problem is how do i send sms to Genymotion is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

A baseband emulation is available on Genymotion.

It embeds SMS and Phone Call.

Available to paid licenses (Business & Indie).

Comment: Oh so now it's not yet available. And i need to use other emulator. Thanks for info i'm looking forward for that.